# Server side datatables server side not working in Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I am using [ignited datatable library](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php) to display records from server side

This is my Controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tryy extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->config->load('category_rules');
        $this->load->library('Datatables');
        $this->load->model('category_model');

    }   


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/add_category1.php');
    }


    public function datatable()
    {
        $this->datatables->select('parent_category_id,parent_category_name')
        ->from('parent_category');
        echo $this->datatables->generate();
    }   

}
```

The datatable() in controller generated following array

```
{
"draw":0,
"recordsTotal":6,
"recordsFiltered":6,
"data":[
{
"parent_category_id":"22",
"parent_category_name":"Live"
},
{
"parent_category_id":"23",
"parent_category_name":"Work"
},
{
"parent_category_id":"24",
"parent_category_name":"Enjoy"
},
{
"parent_category_id":"25",
"parent_category_name":"Move"
},
{
"parent_category_id":"26",
"parent_category_name":"Study"
},
{
"parent_category_id":"27",
"parent_category_name":"Misc"
}
]
}
```

View file(admin/add_category1.php)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="big_table">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>parent category id</th>
 <th>parent category name</th>
 </tr>  
 </thead>  
 <tbody>
  <?php echo $this->table->generate(); ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#big_table').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url('tryy/datatable'); ?>',
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "parent_category_id" },
            { "mDataProp": "parent_category_name" }
        ]
    } );
} );

</script>
```

Data is  getting displayed but

Search ,sort,Show no of records drop down is not functioning

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used this code.. and my server side datatable works like charm

Controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tryy extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
        $this->config->load('category_rules');
        $this->load->model('category_model','parent_category');

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/add_category1.php');
    }

    public function ajax_list()
    {
        error_reporting(0);
        $list = $this->parent_category->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
        foreach ($list as $person) {
            $no++;
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $person->parent_category_id;
            $row[] = $person->parent_category_name;

            //add html for action
            $row[] = 
                  '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';

            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->parent_category->count_all(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->parent_category->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

}
```

Model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Category_model extends CI_Model {


    var $table = 'parent_category';


    var $column = array('parent_category_id','parent_category_name');
    var $order = array('parent_category_id' => 'desc');


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {

        $this->db->from($this->table);

        $i = 0;

        foreach ($this->column as $item) 
        {
            if($_POST['search']['value'])
                ($i===0) ? $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']) : $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            $column[$i] = $item;
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order']))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();
    }

    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($where, $data)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function delete_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }


}
```

View

```
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL STYLES -->

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets1/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets1/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css"/>
        <!-- END PAGE LEVEL STYLES -->

    <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTAINER -->
    <div class="page-container">

                               <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>First Name</th>
                                      <th>Last Name</th>
                                      <th style="width:125px;">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>


                                <?php //echo $this->table->generate(); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- END EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->

    </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets1/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets1/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          table = $('#table').DataTable({ 
            "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
            "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.

            // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?php echo site_url('admin/tryy/ajax_list')?>",
                "type": "POST"
            },

            //Set column definition initialisation properties.
            "columnDefs": [
            { 
              "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
              "orderable": false, //set not orderable
            },
            ],

          });
        });

     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the error means, that you have a mismatch between the columns you are calling and showing. But I haven't used the codeigniter library.

On the other hand, you are building the table head wrong, it should be:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="big_table">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>parent category id</th>
        <th>parent category name</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody
```

And I believe, that you don't need mDataProp things, but if you call it, you should use right key names:

Instead of:

```
{ "mDataProp": "parent category id" },
{ "mDataProp": "parent category name" }
```

You should write the names with underscores:

```
{ "mDataProp": "parent_category_id" },
{ "mDataProp": "parent_category_name" }
```

Comment: @Joeg ,
Yes , i have changed the mDataprop as per names its loading data now but search and show number of records functionality is not working...

Comment: Maybe it depends of that you don't have a right title structure in thead. The row is empty.

Comment: i have added proper thead now but i get the same issue
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
    <th>parent category id</th>
                                <th>parent category name</th>
                              </tr>  
                              </thead>

Comment: Is the browser sending data to the server and what does the server respond?

Comment: <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="big_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>parent category id</th>
<th>parent category name</th>
</tr>  
</thead>  
<tbody>
Undefined table data                                 
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: <tbody>
 <?php echo $this->table->generate(); ?>
</tbody>
 
This is not loading table data

Comment: Is that the respond you get after searching?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85413/discussion-between-chaitanya-koripella-and-joerg).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead of using a `ignited datatable library`

```
function datatable()
        {

                $aColumns = array('parent_category_id','parent_category_name');

                $sTable = 'parent_category';


                $iDisplayStart = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);
                $iDisplayLength = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
                $iSortCol_0 = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_0', true);
                $iSortingCols = $this->input->get_post('iSortingCols', true);
                $sSearch = $this->input->get_post('sSearch', true);
                $sEcho = $this->input->get_post('sEcho', true);

                // Paging
                if(isset($iDisplayStart) && $iDisplayLength != '-1')
                {
                        $this->db->limit($this->db->escape_str($iDisplayLength), $this->db->escape_str($iDisplayStart));
                }

                // Ordering
                if(isset($iSortCol_0))
                {
                        for($i=0; $i<intval($iSortingCols); $i++)
                        {
                                $iSortCol = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_'.$i, true);
                                $bSortable = $this->input->get_post('bSortable_'.intval($iSortCol), true);
                                $sSortDir = $this->input->get_post('sSortDir_'.$i, true);

                                if($bSortable == 'true')
                                {
                                        $this->db->order_by($aColumns[intval($this->db->escape_str($iSortCol))], $this->db->escape_str($sSortDir));
                                }
                        }
                }

                /* 
                 * Filtering
                 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
                 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
                 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
                 */
                if(isset($sSearch) && !empty($sSearch))
                {
                        for($i=0; $i<count($aColumns); $i++)
                        {
                                $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true);

                                // Individual column filtering
                                if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
                                {
                                        $this->db->or_like($aColumns[$i], $this->db->escape_like_str($sSearch));
                                }
                        }
                }

                // Select Data


                $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS '.str_replace(' , ', ' ', implode(', ', $aColumns)), false);


                $rResult = $this->db->get($sTable);

                // Data set length after filtering
                $this->db->select('FOUND_ROWS() AS found_rows');

                $iFilteredTotal = $this->db->get()->row()->found_rows;

                // Total data set length
                $iTotal = $this->db->count_all($sTable);

                // Output
                $output = array(
                        'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
                        'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
                        'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
                        'aaData' => array()
                );

                foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow)
                {
                        $row = array();

                        foreach($aColumns as $col)
                        {

                           $row[] = $aRow['parent_category_id'];

                           $row[] = $aRow['parent_category_name'];  


                        }

                        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
                        //print_r($output['aaData']);
                }

                echo json_encode($output);

        }
```

In Your view file.

```
$('#big_table').dataTable({
                    "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                    "sProcessing": "DataTables is currently busy",
                    "processing": true,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": true,
                    "bLengthChange": true,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url('tryy/datatable'); ?>",
                    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50,100], [10, 25, 50,100]],
                    "sSortAsc": [[1, 'desc']],
                    "iDisplayLength": 10,   
                    "dom": 'Zlfrtip',
                    "bDeferRender": true
            });
```

Your table html will be like.

```
<table id="big_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>parent_category_id</th>                                                 
        <th>parent_category_name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```